# No qualifying bean of type [javax.sql.DataSource] found for dependency [javax.sql.DataSource]

Tags: spring, maven, spring-mvc

when autowired the datasource ,the project will appear error,when i remove the datasource ,the project works normal. i have add the datasource beans in the spring,i do not know where is wrong
i put my project on git address is:

git@github.com:liwei-green/springMVC.git
pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0  http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.spring</groupId>
<artifactId>springMVC</artifactId>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>springMVC Maven Webapp</name>
<url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.1.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.1.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.0-alpha-1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.30</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.7.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.1.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.1.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
<build>
    <finalName>springMVC</finalName>
</build>
</project>
```

the spring

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"  xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context- 4.1.xsd">
<!-- 加载配置文件 -->
<!-- 扫描service自动注入为bean -->
<context:component-scan base-package="com.springdemo" />
<context:property-placeholder location="jdbc.properties" />
<context:annotation-config />

<bean id="dataSource"
    class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName">
        <value>${jdbc.driver}</value>
    </property>
    <property name="url">
        <value>${jdbc.url}</value>
    </property>
    <property name="username">
        <value>${jdbc.username}</value>
    </property>
    <property name="password">
        <value>${jdbc.password}</value>
    </property>
</bean>
<beans>
```

the DemoController.java

```
package com.springdemo.controller;

import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.sql.DataSource;

import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

import com.springdemo.entity.User;
import com.springdemo.service.UserService;

@Controller
public class DemoController {
@Autowired
private UserService userService;
/*加上
@Autowired
private DataSource dataSource
编译报错，没有这句编译正常*/
@Autowired
private DataSource dataSource;

@RequestMapping("login.do")
public ModelAndView  index(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
    request.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
    System.out.println(userService);
    System.out.println(dataSource);
    String userName=request.getParameter("userName");

    String userAge=request.getParameter("userAge");

    User user= userService.findById(3);
    if(userName.equals(user.getName())){
        return new ModelAndView("sys/success","user",user);
    }else{
        return new ModelAndView("sys/faild","user",user);
    }





}

}
```

jdbc.properties

```
jdbc.driver = com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
jdbc.url=mysql://localhost:3306/maven?useUnicode=true&amp;characterEncoding=UTF-8
jdbc.username = root
jdbc.password = 123456

#hibernate config
hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
hibernate.show_sql = true
hibernate.format_sql = false
hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto = update
hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache = true
hibernate.cache.use_query_cache = true
hibernate.cache.region.factory_class =    org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.EhCacheRegionFactory
hibernate.cache.provider_configuration_file_resource_path = ehcache.xml
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Svox0.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The context config listener is missing in web.xml, so the beans in spring.xml are not init, you can add these to your web.xml,

```
<listener>  
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>  
</listener>
```

BTW: spring.xml path is not correct in the web.xml, you can change to this.

```
<context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>classpath:spring.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
```

Comment: thank you very much ,the listener i forget to add,i was trapped in here for three days